# KDE login/logout issues in Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, shutdown

I'm running a fresh Kubuntu installation on a new computer. Everything runs smooth except logging in and out of KDE. The problem could be divided into two parts:

1. About 40% of the time, KDE won't start. All I see is a black screen with **no** mouse cursor. I discovered that I can fix this issue by switching to tty1 and running these two commands:

   ```
   systemctl stop sddm
   systemctl start sddm
   ```
2. I can't shut down my computer properly. Leave/Shut down in KDE doesn't do anything most of the time. The only way to shut down the computer without using the power button is to log out of KDE and then issue the shutdown command in tty1. Note that if I don't log out first, the computer hangs. Logging out of KDE doesn't work properly either. It causes tty7 to turn black but it allows the shutdown command to run in tty1.

Note that `~/.Xauthority` belongs to my user, not `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, it turns out that the NVIDIA driver was to blame for everything. The default NVIDIA proprietary driver that ships with Kubuntu 15.10 has a lot of bugs, especially with newer cards such as GTX 960M.

The solution is to add [this repo](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04). After installing the latest version (currently 364.12) and rebooting all the problems disappeared.